# Are date literals faster than using to_date?

Tags: oracle

Which of these is faster? Are there any other differences?

A.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    my_date >= DATE '2013-01-17';
```

B.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    my_date >= TO_DATE('17/01/2013','dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Comment: It's faster to type a literal than to_date with a format mask (which it should always have of course); does that count? Testing in a PL/SQL loop with `select ... from dual` they seem to be indistinguishable.

Comment: It's difficult to test because there's some fluctuations in the vortex, but they're generally within about 50ms of each other over 100,000 iterations. The date literal is ahead more often but they've just come out identical. In other words there might be a difference but it's at most 0.5 micro seconds (i.e. not worrying about as Alex and Justin have said).

Answer (score 4):

It is highly unlikely to be meaningfully different.  If your bottleneck is how quickly you can convert string literals to dates, I would tend to declare victory and toast the first perfectly tuned application in history.  Or seriously question what I'm doing wrong that forces so many literals to need to be converted into dates.

Theoretically, it should be a bit faster to use a date literal simply because the format is fixed so you don't have the complexity of first parsing the format mask and then parsing the string.  But that assumes that internally Oracle bothered writing the optimized date literal path rather than internally going through the `to_date` code path (which may depend on the specific Oracle version).  And, like I said, if you're in a position where this difference is material, you've either done something very wrong or you've tuned the application so thoroughly that it's almost certainly time to stop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, date literals are faster.  `TO_DATE` is a bug and should be avoided.  (It's not *always* a bug but it's helpful to always be skeptical of it.)

Based on Stackoverflow questions, date handling is one of the trickiest parts of Oracle.  Believing strings and dates are the same thing causes a lot of problems.  Understanding the importance of literals and always using the correct data type will indirectly lead to improved performance.  For example, Entity-Attribute-Value anti-patterns look more suspicious when developers stop constantly casting strings to dates.

It's true that the time to process a date literal and a `TO_DATE` are probably the same or irrelevant.  It's also true that date literals are internally converted to a `TO_DATE` anyway.  But there's more to performance than that.  From a compiler and optimizer perspective, date literals make it easier to *understand* the code, which leads to improved performance.

Here are two examples of where date literals can significantly improve performance.

**Reduced Hard Parsing**

National Language Support (NLS) makes it difficult for Oracle to precisely distinguish between variables and literals, when `TO_DATE` is used.

*We* may be able to assume that we're coding for English language, in America, with a Gregorian calendar.  And we may often (unfairly) take advantage of American coding hegemony and assume other developers understand our system.  But the optimizer must assume the worst case and check date strings very carefully.

Take this statement:

```
select * from dual where trunc(sysdate) = to_date('06-AUG-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

Oracle parses it, and then stores a SQL_ID that is a hash of the entire string.  But with dates, the exact same statement has a different meaning if one of the many NLS parameters change.  Changing NLS parameters can lead to increased hard-parsing with ambiguous `TO_DATE`.  Date literals always parse the same way.

**Better Execution Plans**

Similar to the parsing issue, when Oracle can't quite understand the meaning of a predicate it can lead to poor execution plans.  For example, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253731/oracle-uses-or-ignores-indexed-column-depending-on-the-format-of-to-dateliteral/24459079#24459079) I show has a trivial change in `TO_DATE` formats can produce changes between static and dynamic partition pruning.  That change leads to worse statistics, which leads to a bad execution plan.

**Summary**

Always use date literals instead of `TO_DATE`.  Performance is usually the same.  But date literals are significantly faster in some cases, indirectly lead to better coding practices, are more standardized (ISO 8601), can be checked at compile-time instead of run-time, are less ambiguous to an international audience, and are easier to type.

Using date literals is one of the few coding style decisions you can make that is better in every possible way.