# is 'to_timestamp' applied to every each rows?

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I need to query a big table (I'm using oracle )

and query sentence must search the table by timestamp data type

eg

```
SELECT * 
FROM rec 
WHERE timscolumn between to_timestamp('2023-07-02 00:00:00', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND to_timestamp('2023-08-25 23:59:59', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

My question is ,
does the `to_timestamp` function applied to every each rows?

for e.g.

my rec table have 100000000000 rows
and I need to search date between 2023-01-10 ~ 2023-12-10
and timestamp type column is named timscolumn .
I have index on times column.

when I query,
does `to_timestamp` function applied to every each rows?
I mean

**does database do perform conversion(string -> timestamp) on every each rows for comparision?**

In that case, I think that can cause serious performance issue.
( I already suffered serious performance issue while fetching the table, did query tuning and problem solved but I'm still not sure it it's okay to use `to_timestamp` )

I'm sorry if it's duplicated question. I googled that but didn't find yet
It would be very helpful If you can link any good references or give me any explanation
thank you

Comment: No. Also look at the execution plan to check it is using the index you expect. (And if your column values have fractional seconds you'll miss data in the last second of the last day - e.g. 2023-08-25 23:59:59.123. Using >= and < the following day, instead of between, avoids that and can be clearer. Using timestamp literals is also clearer and shorter.)

Answer (score 3):

> does database do perform conversion(string -> timestamp) on every each rows for comparision?

No. You are converting the string literals `'2023-07-02 00:00:00'` and `'2023-08-25 23:59:59'` to a `TIMESTAMP` and not the column `timscolumn` (which I assume is already a `TIMESTAMP`) so, no, the conversion of the literals can be done once and applied to all the rows.

However, you could re-write the query to use `TIMESTAMP` literals and then there would be no need to convert anything:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   rec 
WHERE  timscolumn BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2023-07-02 00:00:00'
                      AND TIMESTAMP '2023-08-25 23:59:59';
```

and you could also fix the query (assuming that you are not using `TIMESTAMP(0)`) so that it does not exclude timestamps between `2023-08-25 23:59:59.000000001` and `2023-08-25 23:59:59.999999999`:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   rec 
WHERE  timscolumn BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2023-07-02 00:00:00.000000000'
                      AND TIMESTAMP '2023-08-25 23:59:59.999999999';
```

or more simply:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   rec 
WHERE  timscolumn >= TIMESTAMP '2023-07-02 00:00:00'
AND    timscolumn <  TIMESTAMP '2023-08-26 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no conversion in your code.

As `timscolumn`'s datatype already is `timestamp`, everything is OK on the left side. Right side should be modified, though. If year is represented by 4 digits, use `yyyy` format model, not only `yy`.

---

It *would* matter if `timscolumn` was e.g. `varchar2` and you'd then convert it to timestamp as e.g.

```
WHERE to_timestamp(timscolumn, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') between ...
```

In that case, index on `timscolumn` wouldn't be used. You could, though, create a **function-based** index, then.

---

As of performance itself: if table contains 100.000.000.000 rows, it'll take time to return the result.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers correctly answered your literal question, the premise of your question is wrong. Even if Oracle did stupidly perform the variable conversion once for every row, it wouldn't matter because **the time required to run built-in functions is irrelevant to SQL performance.** The amount of CPU time needed to convert 10 billion strings to dates is a rounding error compared to the amount of time needed to read or join 10 billion rows.

To ensure that Oracle data is read and joined as efficiently as possible, you need to create the right physical data structures (indexes, partitions, materialized views, etc.), and you need to give the Oracle optimizer enough information to predict cardinalities and choose the best algorithms for reading and joining the data. You can provide more helpful information by stating literals and expressions as simply and as clearly as possible. If you're worried about performance, you should worry about the algorithms and data structures used in the execution plan.

For this specific case, you can give the optimizer slightly more information by using timestamp literals, as MT0 suggested. Expressions using a `TO_DATE` or a `TO_TIMESTAMP` are not nearly as "literal" as you may think. Different sessions may have different time zones, month names, or calendars. Your `TO_TIMESTAMP` expression doesn't fully identify all that information, so it's possible that your `to_timestamp('2023-07-02 00:00:00', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` may be another user's `to_timestamp('2023-07-02 00:00:00', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'nls_calendar=''thai buddha''')`. While that situation is unlikely, Oracle still has to plan for it, which can have some [rare performance implications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24459079/409172) for all sessions.

Use literals as much as possible.